# iOS IBDesignable interface builder

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I have created a custom `UIButton` with a custom background image, font and different font size based on device(iPad or iPhone). But in the `interface builder` it keeps using the `iPad` resources when i set the size class on compact or the Simulated Matrics size on `iPhone x-inch`.

Is it possible that the interface builder is using the right resources for the right simulated device/size?

```
@IBDesignable
class BlueButton:UIButton
{
    private var isInitialized:Bool = false

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if(!isInitialized)
        {
            isInitialized = true
            self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(name: Style.ButtonImageBlue), forState: .Normal)
            self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Style.FontName, size: UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ? Style.FontSizePad : Style.FontSizePhone)
        }
    }
}
```